# How does Token Generation Event (TGE) work?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ico

I can see ICO has been replaced with TGE for many token sales.

Does *Token Generation Event* refer to the owner of contract minting the token **everytime** when it goes through an event like private seed, private presale, public presale, etc? (term TGE sounds like it should generate tokens upon an event)

So for example, total supply is expected to be 100M and token economics are say,

- private seed 5%
- private presale 10%
- public presale 25%

Then upon the private presale round, it will mint 10M tokens in advance? or is it the other way around where the contract initially sets 100M to owner and the owner would send 10M to private presale contract?

How does a startup usually go through these rounds?
code snippets or contract examples would be appreciated!